# Nonsensical exception: The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, casting

I have a problem with this exception. The exception is thrown only in Chrome. I can open website correctly in the other browsers and in Chrome too for a while sometimes, when I close VS, open older version of this project, close it and reopen the newest version of project.

Exception is thrown from all views.

What can be source of the problem and how can I solve it please?

[image: Error]

[image: Error]

Comment: Looks to me like your DB schema and your entity model don't match.

Comment: Did you change the primary key type that asp.net identity uses?

Comment: I deleted and remade the database and it is working for now.